# XPages Resource Servlet

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

my xPages app (with oneUI theme set) works perfect when I use e.g. this URL:

```
      https://testserver.xxxx.xxxx.com/app_folder/Home.xsp
```

and then our Domino admin mapped it to a new URL

```
      https://myApp.xxxx.xxxx.com
```

that by default opens Home.xsp page

but now I see several UI issues - some icons/images are not shown, some controls displayed incorrectly.
What could cause this problem? It's the same Domino server but just two different ways to log in. Is it something related to "XPages Resource Servlet" configuration? Where can I check it?

For example. I have an image on xPage that has following resource:

```
      "../../oneuiv2/images/sortDescending.png"
```

then when I log in through https://myApp.xxxx.xxxx.com - it doesn't show the image...
OK, then I replaced it with:

```
      "/.ibmxspres/domino/oneuiv2/images/sortDescending.png"
```

same result.
but this works:

```
      "/.ibmxspres/global/theme/oneui/images/sortDescending.gif"
```

I can replace all images/icons with new resource URLs but anyway other standard controls are not shown correctly..

Comment: Use FireBug/devtools to identify exact response for resource request. It may relate to SSO/authorization, or invalid path.

Comment: OK.. it just says "Failed to load the given URL"

Comment: It's like "XPages Resource Servlet" doesn't work properly.. because "/.ibmxspres/global" alias works, but "/.ibmxspres/domino" doesn't

Comment: no, look at response: you could get 200 (login form), 401/403 (not authorized) or 404 (malformed url)

Comment: OK.. it says 404 Not Found... So why first link works https://testserver.xxxx.xxxx.com/oneuiv2/images/sortDescending.png  but this one doesn't: https://myApp.xxxx.xxxx.com/oneuiv2/images/sortDescending.png


it's the same Domino server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.. it's fixed. The problem was in Virtual Server Mapping document.

Names.nsf -> Web -> Web Configuration -> Virtual Server -> Mapping tab...

we had to set

```
   HTML directory: domino\html
```

which was

```
   HTML directory: /myappdbname.nsf
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

Based on our short discussion your problem is in wrong URLs.
So why one URL works and the other one doesn't? Concatenation, in my opinion. Browser, JS frameworks (DOJO) and JS programmers in general tend to use either relative URLs or cut/concatenate URL string. This my result into URL that is not understandable by server.

In your case check URL mapping made by your admin - does it apply to all URL formats used by XPages? Are those transformed URLs accessible on server (enter them in URL bar of browser)? That is the key to get your XPage working.